# How to convert $\alpha = \cos(\frac{8\pi}{11})+ i \sin(\frac{8\pi}{11})$ into $\text{n}^{th}$ roots of unity format?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

Context: Preparing for JEE and it is one of the practice problems.

**Question:**

> If $\alpha = cos(\frac{8\pi}{11})+ i sin(\frac{8\pi}{11})$ then $\Re({\alpha+\alpha^2+\alpha^3+\alpha^4+\alpha^5})$ is equal to 
> A) $\frac{1}{2}$
>
> B) $-\frac{1}{2}$
>
> C) $0$
>
> D) None
> Key: Option B

What I've tried:
$$\alpha+\alpha^2+\alpha^3+\alpha^4+\alpha^5 = e^\frac{8\pi}{11}+e^\frac{16\pi}{11}+e^\frac{24\pi}{11}+e^\frac{32\pi}{11}+e^\frac{40\pi}{11}$$
**Then I was struck here knowing that the given argument is not in form of $\frac{2k\pi}{n}$ so now I cant use $\text{n}^{th}$ root of unity**
So what should I do now? Is there any way to convert in form of $\alpha = e^{i(\frac{2k\pi}{n})}$
where $k = {0, 1, ... n-1}?$

 Or is there any other way to solve it?

Comment: Apply Formula of GP. BTW you must write $\alpha=e^{\frac{i 8\pi}{11}}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roots of unity is indeed the correct approach here, rather than geometric series.

$a^{11} = 1$ and $a \bar{a} = 1$. Thus the conjugate of $a$, $\bar{a} = \frac{1}{a} = \frac{1}{a} \cdot a^{11} = a^{10}$, which has the same real part as $a$. Now since:

$$1 + (a + a^2 + \cdots + a^5) + (a^6 + a^7 + \cdots + a^{10})$$
$$ = 1 + (a + a^2 + \cdots + a^5) + (\overline{a^5} + \overline{a^4}+ \cdots + \bar{a}) = 0,$$
it hence follows that the real part is $-1/2$.

Comment: To build some intuition: imagine the 11th roots of unity on the complex plane. Then counting the 'dots', $\omega^{10}$ is the mirror image of $\omega$ across the $x$-axis. Now if we raise everything to the power of $8$, which means increasing the angle by $8$ times with the same radius speaking geometrically, it's immediately clear that $\bar{a} = a^{10}$.

Comment: The sum of $n$-th roots of unity has to be 0 as it is the coefficient of $z^{n-1}$ in the polynomial $z^n - 1.$

Comment: Sorry for the typo, I was probably thinking of something else.